# Same screen size different css behaviour - Responsive Website Material ui

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

Same page is behaving different on Android and iOS, even on different browser as well. I am clueless to understand the issue. Is there has be some changes for view-port.

Below are two comparisons that I have as of now, first one is working as expected and in second one components are overlapping.

[Working as expected (350 width chrome simulating mobile device)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npHGo.png)

[Failed (400+ width on iphone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4gdq.jpg)

**Edit 1-**

Below is the website URL
https://www.swadhaarani.com/subscription-kits/home-care-kit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no"
      />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Please share some sample code to investigate what's really happening.

Comment: You should give a minimum height to main tag that everything wrap. But can,t say it exactly because of there is no code in your question.Please add code to your question.

Comment: @JanithaRasanga I have added the code for viewport also added the website link